# Index column values in 2D array using array of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following array:

```
import numpy as np 

print(A)
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  5,  8,  7],
       [ 5,  3,  4,  1,  8, 11],
       [ 2,  7,  5,  3,  4,  1],
       [ 2,  8,  8,  1, 10,  1],
       [ 2, 14,  8,  6,  5,  3]])
```

And I need to the values `A` corresponding to these column indices:

```
b = np.array([5, 0, 3, 4, 4])
```

Expected output:

```
array([ 7,  5,  3, 10,  5])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the expected output

Comment: Edited to include :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). You need to define an indexing array across the first axis, so that both indexing arrays are broadcast together and each column index *refers* to a specific row. In this case you just want an `np.arange` to index on the rows:

```
A[np.arange(A.shape[0]), b]
# array([ 7,  5,  3, 10,  5])
```